# MacOS Mojave: How do I change the default /Users directory for ALL users logging in?

Tags: mojave, user-account, symlink, active-directory

I've seen this question answered in various forms for other iterations of Mac OS X, but Mojave is proving a bit more challenging. In short:

I have several dual drive systems, (SSD and HDD) with the OS installed on the smaller SSD and a desire for all User directories to be located on the larger HDD. These Macs will be joined to a Windows Active Directory domain to facilitate authentication of users.

Traditionally, the change of /Users directory can be accomplished via the "advanced options" under Users in the Control Center. However, there is one major drawback to this: It must be done for EACH user who logs into the system. I'm looking for a solution that would allow this change to be automatically instated (set as the default) for each NEW user logging in.

In the past, I've skirted around this issue by creating a symlink that points the /Users directory to the new location on the larger HDD. However, Mojave is no longer allowing me to perform this procedure (automatically creating the symlink a directory DOWN in /Users, and when attempting to remove and recreate the /Users directory via symlink, I receive "Operation Not Permitted."). Even so, this solution was non ideal as some programs detest symlinks.

I have not yet attempted to mount the HDD at /Users, as I would prefer to not have the entire directory meant solely for that space. I have read, however, that Mojave and sandboxd throw a fit when this setup is implemented so I have not pursued it yet.

Does anyone happen to know of a way to change the default location of /Users, to change the default behavior of directory location creation for newly created users?

Thanks!

Comment: Dis you try disabling SIP and then using the Terminal to create the Symlink? I would very much expect that to work.

Comment: AH! I had forgotten about that change! As a matter of fact, disabling SIP, creating the Symlink, and re-enabling it has worked. Thanks! For the moment, this has me moving forward again. But I would still like to know of a way to change the default location for all users and avoid a symlink entirely.

Comment: Glad it worked! I suspect a symlink is actually going to be the best solution, as macOS uses a lot of hardcoded paths.